# Unable to see www-data owned folder logged in via FTP

Tags: nginx, debian

I have a user "devuser" which when I log in via SSH can view all files. Specifically /var/www folders, there are 2 folders testsite mainsite. But when logging in via SSH using FTP in WinSCP application I can not view files owned by www-data. So I can see mainsite but not testsite. It seems as if my user permissions using ftp are different somehow.

I have tried adding my user "devuser" to the www-data group even after a server restart my user is not able to view the folder "testsite".

I'm using Debian 8 & Nginx to serve web pages.

If I have not provided enough info I apologise in advance, please let me know what to provide.

`ls -la` in `www` folder shows:

```
drwxrwsr-x  4 root     root     4096 Sep 27 21:20 .
drwxr-xr-x 12 root     root     4096 Sep 27 21:20 ..
drwxrwsr-x  8 www-data www-data 4096 Sep 27 21:20 testsite
drwxrwsr-x  2 root     root     4096 Sep 27 21:20 mainsite
```

cat of `/etc/passwd`:

```
devuser:x:1000:1000:devuser,,,:/home/devuser:/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear from your answer, but I am suspecting you are using the sftp subsystem of openssh.

If that is the case, please see my answer here:

[Best practice for WordPress, direct auto updates and SFTP access for users](https://serverfault.com/questions/721532/best-practice-for-wordpress-direct-auto-updates-and-sftp-access-for-users/721630#721630)

As well as:

[bad ownership or modes for chroot directory component](https://serverfault.com/questions/584986/bad-ownership-or-modes-for-chroot-directory-component)

> **ChrootDirectory**
>   Specifies the pathname of a directory to chroot(2) to after
>   authentication.  ***All components of the pathname must be root-owned 
>   directories that are not writable by any other user or
>   group***.  After the chroot, sshd(8) changes the working directory
>   to the user's home directory.