# Restrict SFTP users to their home folder

Tags: sftp

I want to restrict SFTP users to their home folder so that they won't see anybody else's folder/home directories. Unfortunately all SFTP users can see other user's folders at the moment. All the posts and examples points out `ChrootDirectory` but for some reason I cannot get it working.

```
$ sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match Group sftp
  ChrootDirectory %h            # The %h causes "Broken pipe" error while trying to login
  ChrootDirectory /var/sftp     # This allows login but all SFTP folders are visible to all user
  X11Forwarding no
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  AllowAgentForwarding no
  PermitTunnel no
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

**Users, Permissions and Folders**

I used command below to create users and folders.

```
sudo useradd -m -d /var/sftp/hello -G sftp hello --shell /usr/sbin/nologin
```

Result

```
ubuntu@linux:~$ grep hello /etc/passwd
hello:x:1001:1002::/var/sftp/hello:/usr/sbin/nologin

ubuntu@linux:~$ grep world /etc/passwd
world:x:1002:1003::/var/sftp/world:/usr/sbin/nologin

ubuntu@linux:~$ ls -l /var/
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root   4096 May  7 14:48 sftp

ubuntu@linux:~$ ls -l /var/sftp/
drwxr-xr-x 3 hello sftp 4096 May  7 14:01 hello
drwxr-xr-x 2 world sftp 4096 May  7 14:48 world
```

**SOLUTION**

The problem here is that, I had to let `root:root` own the home folder of my users and create another folder under users' home folder (e.g. `uploads`) then own it as `hello|world:sftp`. Originally the home folders were owned by `hello|world:sftp`.

Comment: What is in your sshd logs when you get "Broken pipe" error?

Comment: `linux sshd[3555]: fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory "/var/sftp/hello"` and `linux sshd[3555]: fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory "/var/sftp/world"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bad ownership or modes for chroot directory component](https://serverfault.com/questions/584986/bad-ownership-or-modes-for-chroot-directory-component)

Answer (score 2):

For security reasons users under `chroot` shouldn't be able to create arbitrary files (for example `/etc/shadow` and countless others). That's why sshd forces you to take away ownership and writing privilege of the chrooted directory itself:

```
chown root:root /var/sftp/hello
chmod o-w       /var/sftp/hello
```

Alternative solution, without any sshd `ChrootDirectory` depends on the fact that user can only list a directory if they have `r` permission, while using it requires only `x` permission:

```
chown root:root /var/sftp
chmod o=x       /var/sftp    # implicitly removes rw, sets only x
```

Comment: If I change the ownership to `root:root` my user `hello` can login. However, I want `hello` to be able to write/upload files into `/var/sftp/hello` folder which is currently not working.

Comment: I had to create sub folder under home folder then let individual users own it. That was the problem.